# Trigger when application is not active

Tags: winforms

I have an application(Winform, TAB based MDI application), now we are adding few features. These Features are developed in WPF. A new form contains Element host, which will host this WPF User control. This newly added Form is displayed in every Tab's one corner. When application minimizes/Maximizes events are trigger, through these I am able to show or hide this new form. Also, this new form's Topmost Property is set true.

But when main form is still showing and when another application(like a note pad) is opened, the newly added form displayed over this notepad. The new form supposed to go behind the notepad, but it is always top.

Any suggestion on how to send it back.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Selected answer from 
[Detect when application becomes active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615744/detect-when-application-becomes-active) post solved my problem.

I am also capturing

```
main.Deactivate += new EventHandler(main_Deactivate);
```

Thank you.